# Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android-studio, firebase, gradle, android-gradle

Ошибка при подключении Firebase Analytics.
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

implementation('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
implementation 'wzd.anarchy:library:unspecified'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0-beta-3'
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'
}
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
implementation "com.polidea.rxandroidble:rxandroidble:1.4.3"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно разрешить конфликт версий либо обновив версию плагина google-services, либо обновив версию com.google.android.gms до версии 16.0.1.

Ваш переводчик сообщений ошибок на русский.